# Access full page source in WatiN

Tags: watin

I am looking for a way to pass my webpages through a DTD validator as part of my WatiN tests, but I haven't found a clean way to access the raw HTML yet. Is there a built-in way to do it?

I think I could access the property `IE.InternetExplorer` and `QueryInterface` for the `IPersistStreamInit` interface and serialize the document to an `IStream`, but it seems like a lot of work for what I guess must be a fairly common task.

Am I missing something obvious in WatiN? Or can someone think of a better solution than the one I outlined above? That solution is very IE specific after all.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you access the source code:

```
browser.ActiveElement.Parent.OuterHtml
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I recall right then OuterHtml returns the HTML code as it looks after having been altered by IE. My guess is that IE interprets the HTML and builds a DOM. When you access OuterHtml IE serializes the DOM back to text format and this is slightly different from the original. I want a verbatim copy of the HTML so that I can run validation on it.

Answer (score 1):

string html = browser.Body.Parent.OuterHtml;

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be a better way. I filed a [feature request](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2857965&group_id=167632&atid=843730) and submitted a patch at WatiN's sourceforge tracker instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thought to drop some lines to help anyone struggling out there to get the pristine HTML source of a web page via WatiN without, however, patching WatiN - just as a matter of taste.

So capitalizing on Johan Levin's patch I bolted together the following. Be safe and hope you find it useful.

```
    private static TextVariant GetWebPageSource(IE browser)
    {
    IHTMLDocument2 htmlDocument = ((IEDocument)(browser.DomContainer.NativeDocument)).HtmlDocument;
    Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(htmlDocument.charset);
        IPersistStreamInit persistStream = (IPersistStreamInit)htmlDocument;
        MinimalIStream stream = new MinimalIStream();
        persistStream.Save(stream, false);
        return new TextVariant(encoding.GetString(stream.ToArray()));
    }

    [Guid("7FD52380-4E07-101B-AE2D-08002B2EC713")]
    [InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IPersistStreamInit
    {
        void GetClassID(out Guid pClassID);
        int IsDirty();
        void Load(IStream pStm);
        void Save(IStream pStm, bool fClearDirty);
        void GetSizeMax(out long pcbSize);
        void InitNew();
    }

    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601355/passing-an-fstream-or-equivalent-from-c-to-c-through-cli
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)]
    public class MinimalIStream : MemoryStream, IStream
    {
        public MinimalIStream() { }

        public MinimalIStream(byte[] data) : base(data) { }

        #region IStream Members
        public void Write(byte[] pv, int cb, IntPtr pcbWritten)
        {
            base.Write(pv, 0, cb);
            if (pcbWritten != IntPtr.Zero)
                Marshal.WriteInt64(pcbWritten, (long)cb);
        }

        public void Stat(out STATSTG pstatstg, int grfStatFlag)
        {
            pstatstg = new STATSTG();
            pstatstg.cbSize = base.Length;
        }

        public void Read(byte[] pv, int cb, IntPtr pcbRead)
        {
            long bytes_read = base.Read(pv, 0, cb);
            if (pcbRead != IntPtr.Zero) Marshal.WriteInt64(pcbRead, bytes_read);
        }

        public void Seek(long dlibMove, int dwOrigin, IntPtr plibNewPosition)
        {
            long pos = base.Seek(dlibMove, (SeekOrigin)dwOrigin);
            if (plibNewPosition != IntPtr.Zero) Marshal.WriteInt64(plibNewPosition, pos);
        }

        public void Clone(out IStream ppstm)
        {
            ppstm = null;
        }

        public void Commit(int grfCommitFlags)
        {
        }

        public void CopyTo(IStream pstm, long cb, IntPtr pcbRead, IntPtr pcbWritten)
        {
        }

        public void LockRegion(long libOffset, long cb, int dwLockType)
        {
        }

        public void SetSize(long libNewSize)
        {
        }

        public void Revert()
        {
        }

        public void UnlockRegion(long libOffset, long cb, int dwLockType)
        {
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: Not working. Seems to take only the begining but not all of the sources.

Comment: Add Below code before calling GetWebPageSource() to get the complete text:

Answer (score 0):

I found:

```
browser.ActiveElement.Parent.OuterHtml
```

will not always get everything, as is dependant on your 'ActiveElement', Therefore:

```
browser.Body.Parent.OuterHtml
```

seems to work better. (`browser` being your instance of IE)

Though I believe Johan Levin is correct in saying the DOM is serialised back to text format.
Therefore would it not be easier to just fetch the document by it's URL (without using WatiN) to validate it.