# MIME MAPI IConverterSession COMException on Activator.CreateInstance

Tags: c#, outlook, mapi

I have been trying to use IConverterSession to convert from EML to MSG (MIME to MAPI), but I keep stumbling on COM errors.
I use a C# MAPIMethods class to wrap IConverterSession (like the one found here : [Save Mail in MIME format (*.eml) in Outlook Add-In](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25381099/save-mail-in-mime-format-eml-in-outlook-add-in)).

First, I had the problems of unknown clsid, solved with this post (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stephen_griffin/2014/04/21/outlook-2013-click-to-run-and-com-interfaces/).

Now that the proper registry keys have been edited, I face a new problem: first, I get an error message `The operating system is not presently configured to run this application`, and I get a COMException: `Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {4E3A7680-B77A-11D0-9DA5-00C04FD65685} failed due to the following error: 8007013d The system cannot find message text for message number 0x in the message file for . (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007013D).`

My code is :

```
    Type converter = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(MAPIMethods.CLSID_IConverterSession, true); 
    object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(converter);
    MAPIMethods.IConverterSession session = (MAPIMethods.IConverterSession)obj;
```

The error is raised on "object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(converter);"

A COMException normally means that "type is a COM object but the class identifier used to obtain the type is invalid, or the identified class is not registered.". So either `Type converter = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(MAPIMethods.CLSID_IConverterSession, true);` does not return the proper type, or there is still a registry key missing somewhere.

I am using Office 15 (2013) C2R 32 bits on Win 64bits. The application is setup on an x86 build configuration.

Is there something I am missing somewhere? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The operating system is not presently configured to run this application" - it sure sounds like your app is compiled as x64 on a machine with a 32 bit version of Outlook.

Have you tried to use Redemption? It wraps `IConverterSession` for .Net languages. Something like the following should do the job.

```
using Redemption;
...
Redemmption.RDOSession session = new Redemmption.RDOSession();
Redemmption.RDOMail msg = session.CreateMessageFromMsgFile(@"c:\temp\test.msg");
msg.Import(@"c:\temp\test.eml", Redemption.rdoSaveAsType.olRFC822);
msg.Save();
```

`olRFC822` format will use `IConverterSession` if it is available or the internal Redemption converter if `IConverterSesison` is not available (e.g. under Exchange version of MAPI or the latest versions of Outlook 2016 C2R where IConverterSession cannot be used).
Use olRFC822_Redemption or olRFC822_Outlook if you always want to force Redemption or Outlook (IConverterSession) converter.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, 
I kinda expected you would answer. Indeed, my machine is 64bits, and Office is 32, but I set the target build as 32 bits.

Comment: How old is your version of Outlook 2013 C2R? MS recently changed Outlook 2016 C2R (don't know about Outlook 2013) that prevents IConverterSession from being created outside of Outlook.

Comment: (I tried to edit my first comment, but it was too late...)
Although it works perfectly fine, I wanted to avoid Redemption, because I would like to share it with my fellow coworkers (we migrated from Lotus to Outlook, and I want to get the emails back). So I tried to keep it as stand-alone as possible.

Comment: And we are using build 15.0.4833.1000, that's all I know.

Comment: Even though I'd prefer to not use Redemption, and understand what's causing the error, I will mark your answer as the answer. But if anyone can assist on the error, I'll gladly take any advice!