# MAPI IconverterSession MAPItoMIME function importing raw MIME text with Outlook 2016 C2R

Tags: outlook, mapi

I've been using the IconverterSession.MIMEtoMAPI function to import EML. This works fine in most cases, but when used with an Outlook 2016 C2R installation I'm only seeing the raw MIME imported as PR_BODY and nothing else.

For a ClickToRun installation I'm not patching the registry but rather creating an OLE from the DLL, with the python code

```
        IconvOLE = ctypes.OleDLL(IconvDLL) 
        clsid_class = uuid.UUID(str(clsid)).bytes_le
        iclassfactory = uuid.UUID(str(pythoncom.IID_IClassFactory)).bytes_le
        com_classfactory = ctypes.c_long(0)
        IconvOLE.DllGetClassObject(clsid_class, iclassfactory, ctypes.byref(com_classfactory))
        MyFactory = pythoncom.ObjectFromAddress(com_classfactory.value, pythoncom.IID_IClassFactory)
        iconverter = MyFactory.CreateInstance (None, str(iid))
```

where the code to search the registry for the DLL is

```
  def SearchRegForDLL (store, reg, clsid, iid) :
      try:
          aReg = winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, store)
          aKey = winreg.OpenKey(aReg, reg, 0, winreg.KEY_READ | winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY)
          dummy_n, IconvDLL, dummy_t = winreg.EnumValue(aKey, 0)
          winreg.CloseKey(aKey)
          winreg.CloseKey(aReg)
          return IconvDLL
      except:
          return None

  clsid = win32com.mapi.mapi.CLSID_IConverterSession
  iid = win32com.mapi.mapi.IID_IConverterSession
  for iconvpath in ("", "16.0", "15.0") :
      regpath =  os.path.join ("Software","Microsoft","Office",iconvpath,"ClickToRun","Registry","Machine","Software","Classes")                     
      if platform.machine() == "AMD64" and platform.architecture()[0] == "32bit":
          # 32bit application on 64bit platform
          regpath = os.path.join (regpath,"Wow6432Node")
      regpath = os.path.join (regpath,"CLSID", str(clsid),"InprocServer32")
      IConvDLL = SearchRegForDLL (winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, regpath, clsid, iid)
```

and I have confirmed  value of win32com.mapi.mapi.CLSID_IConverterSession is IID('{4E3A7680-B77A-11D0-9DA5-00C04FD65685}'). This finds the DLL

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\OUTLMIME.DLL
```

This gives me a valid IconverterSession and I can call the MIMEtoMAPI method without problem. This worked before, but it appears that with Outlook 2016 C2R (I haven"t check the non ClickToRun version of 2016) the raw MIME text is imported as PR_BODY. I have confirmed that the EML is valid and Outlook can load the file by double clicking on it.

I saw the comment from Dmitri in the [following stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41540569/mime-mapi-iconvertersession-comexception-on-activator-createinstance) and when using outlookspy I saw that the IconverterSession button is grey and not accessible. Does this mean that MIMEtoMAPI is no longer available, and if so why, or at least not in Outlook 2016 C2R ? Is there a means to continue to use MIMEtoMAPI ?

Comment: Are you sure you are loading the right dll? If you search the registry for {4e3a7680-b77a-11d0-9da5-00c04fd65685} (which is CLSID_IConverterSession), is it present and where?

Comment: My code to search the registry for the DLL in python is now included bove

Comment: Is IConverterSesison in OutlookSpy always disabled? It is only disabled if no item is select since it needs a message to operate on.